# NP++: Clear all lines which does not contain a certain string

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to find a line in NP++, which does not contain the string (for example)

> marg%233!_

I tried

> .*[^(marg%233!_)].*\r

But that seems wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a negative lookahead, which will fail the whole regex if what's inside is matched:

```
^(?!.*marg%233!_).*\r?
```

and replace these matches with an empty string.

The final `?` is to catch the final line of your file, and this is assuming your linebreaks are `\r`. If it's not you can replace this last character with `([\n\r]|\r\n|\n\r)`.

`[^...]` is a negative character class, it will match any character (and only one haracter, as `[...]` would) which is *not* contained inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to achieve this. You need to perform 2 steps.

1. Go to Search menu > Find... > Select "Mark" Tab. Search for `marg%233!_`. Don't forget to check "Bookmark lines" and Press "Mark All"

   ==> All Rows you want to keep got a Bookmark
2. Go to Menu "Search - Bookmark - Remove Unmarked lines"

   ==> All lines without a bookmark are deleted.